# MySQL: Displaying items based on another table's data

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

keeping it short on my question. Basically, I am working on a Facility booking system for my FYP.

I have designed my database this way:

Facility table:

ID | Room_Name | Capacity

Facility Booking:

ID | Facility_ID | Book_Date

So basically, I have a select list with 3 inputs.

1st Input: Date

2nd Input: Capacity

3rd Input: Room Name

Using ajax, after I had selected the date and inputted the capcity, I want to run through a check on my Facility Booking Table, to check if there's already an existing booking, if there is an existing booking, it will not show in the Room Name (3rd Input). But if the booking doesn't exist, it will show.

NOTE:
My 3rd input (Room Name), is basically a foreach loop, which loops through all the rooms and displays all the room_name in the facility table.

Any kind of guide is appreciate, I've been scratching my head for the past 2-3days, I do not need the code, but just to be pointed in the right direction. Thanks everyone in the community!

Comment: is there any relationship between "Room Number" and "Capacity" ?

Comment: Hi sorry, I forgot to clarify, there are no relationships between the items. The idea of me having capacity is because each room can fit different numbers of people, and by I was just planning to do something simple in my query like SELECT * from facility where Capacity <= $capacity. With $capacity being the number inputted by the people booking the rooms. The flow is basically 1) select a date, 2) input capacity 3) display all available rooms (skipping the rooms which are already booked on the selected date)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you will pass the $capacity and $bookdate to your query.

So just use query like:

```
"Select Room_Name from facility where capacity <=" . $capacity . " and ID not in (select Facility_ID from Booking where Book_date='" . $bookdate . "')"
```

then pass the result to your 3rd input select box

(Reminder: please use parameterized prepared statement in your codes for preventing SQL Injection)

Comment: I just tested with this query (In phpmyadmin):
SELECT room_name from `facility` where capacity > '10' and ID not in (select fac_id from facility_booking where book_date = '2016-12-03');

And the results is just what I wanted, I never knew you could chain queries like this, extremely thankful for your answer. Hopefully this will aid me in my programming career down the road! Thanks!!

Comment: You are welcome. Have a nice day and Happy Coding !